# How to Pass TextBox input to a gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two textbox and one gridview in my webform. The gridview is binded with database. But I want to add one more column on runtime which will be the textbox input from the webform. Because the scenario is like: I am maintaining two formula to calculate some percentage using the two textbox and the client wants to see this calculation for each row in the gridview.

But I cannot do this.

Is there anyone who can help me on this please? May be some suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the column in your GridView markup with a label control to display the result as follows.

Here is the markup needed, please note Visible is set to false.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Use the RowDataBound event to find the label and calculate your result as below:

```
void GridView1GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
 if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
  //find the control
  var label1 = e.Item.FindControl("label1") as Label;
  if (label1 != null)
  {
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbInput1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbInput2.Text))
   {
      // Do the calculation and set the label
      label1.Text = tbInput1.Text + tbInput2.Text;
      // Make the column visible
      GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Please forgive any errors, I have not tested the above.

Comment: sure bro..I would love to do this :)